# Change the simple date time format to show time zone

Tags: php, date-format

I have a simple date time in the format `10/20 4:30PM`. I want it to display in the format 
`10/24 1:30PM -007`. I am saying `date('Y-m-d H:i:sT', $time_recieved)` assuming `T` is for timezone. But It is still not giving the time zone. What might be the reason? Is there any other format I am missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you want is `O` not `T` I believe.

Check the PHP date page for all the format listings possible.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: I just tried what @themazz said. and T shows PST and O showed  -7. So T should be the actually correct answer people. I used  $today = date('Y-m-d H:i:s A T', strtotime('now'));

Answer (score 5):

You can have a look at the official manual of PHP : date ();

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

I tested that and I used on my server with :

```
$time = time(); 
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s T', $time);
```

it shows the timezone perfectly. Check $time_received, it might be an erroneous number, try with local time with time´() function to ensure that it's OK.

Good luck

Comment: This is the correct answer. O shows digits like -7. T actually shows PST, which is what the OP asked for.The OP's code had the T without a space is why his didn't work correctly :-)

Comment: Thank you themazz, your answer helped me.